# Biztalk 2009 + VS 2010 = possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk, biztalk-2009

Is it possible to use Biztalk 2009 with VS 2010?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is [not possible](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/biztalkgeneral/thread/576c9d86-be08-4768-b48c-208246c48a08). That is some strange policy in MS:

- Biztalk 2006 and 2006 R2 = VS 2005
- Biztalk 2009 = VS 2008
- Biztalk 2010 (former name was Biztalk 2009 R2) = VS 2010

Btw. same problems are with Business inteligence studio in SQL Server.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but can you not use Biztalk 2006 with .NET 3.5 as it's just an extension of .NET 2.0?